# Automatizado de vencimientos de pagos

Tags: php, pdo

Hola este estoy haciendo un control de pagos pero quiero automatizar
el mensaje que ha se ha vencido, pero lo malo que con este método solo me actualiza el primer registro que tengo y ya los demás no e intentado con un ciclo `FOR` o no se que estaré haciendo mal.

El ciclo los estoy llamada con un document.ready para que se ejecute el método cuando se abre la pagina.

```php
    public function revisarFecha() { 
        $user = Session::getSession("User");
        if (null !== $user) {
            if ("Admin" == $user["Roles"]) {
       //Obtengo todos los registros de la tabla pagos para detectar la fecha d 
       del vencimiento 
                //A qui tendría que enviar el dato de Id_cliente
                //Pero el problema es que solo me evalúa un registro y 
                //quiero que me evalué todos los registros de la tablas pagos
                $array = array(  
                        1, 
                     );
                $data = $this->model->getPago2($array);

               print_r($data);

                //    $array = $data["results"];
                //   $data2 = $this->model->getPago($array[0]["Id_cliente"]);


                if(is_array($data)) {
                    //Guardamos los results 
                    $array = $data["results"];
                    $fecha = date("d-m-Y");
                    //Si la fecha es la misma que tenemos en la tabla pagos e insertaremos 
                    //En la tabla cliente vencido
                    //Tendria que hacer un ciclo for para que cada registro se evaluara 
                    //Cada ID_cliente y compare fechas para anotar vencidos 
                    if ($array[0]["Fecha_pago"] == $fecha) {


                         $array = array(
                            $array[0]["Id_cliente"],
                            "Vencido",
                      );
                       print_r($this->model->insertarVencido($array));
                    } else {
                       echo 'Funciona correctamente';
                    }
                }
            } else {
                echo "No tiene permitido";
            }
        }
}
```